# Setting a background link URL using JavaScript / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-tag-manager

I am trying to set an element background image and a link URL using jQuery. The background image works when I do the following, but the link does not:

```
<script>

$( ".background" ).css("background-image", "url(https://www.example.com/image1.png)", "href(https://www.example.com)");

</script>
```

I have to use Javascript for this as I have variables set in GTM that are being used to construct the image location URL and the link URL.

Comment: There's no such thing as a 'background link'. What exactly are you trying to achieve? I assume you want to go to that URL when the `.background` element is clicked...?

Comment: Can you provide your *before* and *expected after* html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`href` has nothing to do with css(). Use attr()

```
$( ".background" ).css("background-image", "url(https://www.example.com/image1.png)")
                  .attr('href','https://www.example.com')
```

Comment: Thanks, I also tried this, but it didn't work either?